# HTML5 canvas panorama effect

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, panoramas

I want to make a panorama viewer in HTML5, I have managed to place images in my canvas so that they form the 360 degree image and used a jQuery plugin to make the effect of scrolling sideways. Now to my "problem", I want to make it more spherical feeling by stretching the edges of the image in the canvas when I rotate my image. Like Google does in it's street view, to get a better feel for the depth in the image.

Is the stretching effect something that is possible in HTML5 canvas with or without an JavaScript plugin (feels like someone could have made such a plugin or had the same problem besides Google).

Hope I'm not being to fuzzy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you are asking is how to perform a 3D projection on an HTML5 canvas. Your best approach would be to use wegGL. Take a look at this [example](http://creativejs.com/2012/01/little-planet-street-view/). 
And a [beautiful](http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/streetViewReflectionMapping/#39.36382677360614,8.431220278759724) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try checking out the software Pano2VR by Gnome Software.  The trial version has an unlimited trial time, it just puts stamps on your panoramas.  But it's pretty easy to customize.